# Finding the variance-covariance matrix

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose $σ_0, σ_1$ are positive constants and define random variables $X_1, X_2, . . . X_n$ via
$X_i =$ $σ_0 Z_0 + σ_1 Z_i$
where $Z_0, Z_1, . . . , Z_n$ each have variance $1$ and are uncorrelated to each other.
$(Z_0, Z_1, . . . , Zn_)$ has the standard Gaussian
distribution on $R^(N+1)$

Find the variance-covariance matrix $Σ$ of $X_1, X_2, . . . X_n$, and the variance-covariance matrix $\tilde Σ$ of $X_0, X_1, X_2, . . . X_n$, where $X_0 = σ_ 0Z_0$

I am unsure where to start this. I know that a covariance-variance matrix has inputs of the variance of a variable along the diagonals, and the covariance between the two rows/columns on the other entries, but I'm unsure 1) How to calculate those and 2) How to apply that to this specific example.

Thanks in advance!

Update: I've got $Cov(X_i, X_j)$$=Cov(σ_0 Z_0 + σ_1 Z_i)$ $+Cov(σ_0 Z_0 + σ_1 Z_j$) but I'm not sure on advancing from here.

Comment: You may as well assume without loss of generality that the $Z_i$ have zero mean and so the $X_j$ do too.  Then find $E[X_i X_j]$ using the lack of correlation you know

Comment: @Henry I've updated my question to show my progress so far. Any steps from there appreciated.

Comment: You should have $Cov(X_i, X_j)=Cov(σ_0 Z_0 + σ_1 Z_i,σ_0 Z_0 + σ_1 Z_j) $ $= Cov(σ_0 Z_0,σ_0 Z_0) + Cov(σ_1 Z_i,σ_0 Z_0 ) +Cov(σ_0 Z_0,σ_1 Z_j) + Cov(σ_1 Z_i,σ_1 Z_j)  $

Comment: Thanks I see that now but how can I calculate those values? Obviously the first term is just the variance as they are the same, but how can you calculate that?

Comment: $Cov(aX,bY)=ab\, Cov(X,Y)$

Comment: So is the matrix $σ_0$$^2$ +$σ_i$$^2$ for all the diagonals and just $σ_0$$^2$ for all other points?

Comment: $σ_0$$^2$ +  $+σ_1$$^2$ that should read not $i$

Comment: I think so, except that $Cov(X_0,X_0)=\sigma_0^2$